# Microsoft Office 2010 along with a language pack using Wine

Tags: linux, microsoft-office-2010, wine, language-pack

I've succesfully installed Microsoft Office 2010 on my Ubuntu linux (14.04) using Wine with Playonlinux. No problem here. What I'm trying to achieve (again) is to install both the English and Hungarian languages (proofing and interface language).

What I've tried so far:

- Installing both in succession. This works on Windows, but doesn't seem to work within Wine ("configuration failed" at the end of the second install)...
- Installing one and a language pack. (Same output as the previous.)
- Installing one and only the proofing. Doesn't seem to work either...
- Installing both in succession. Copying several files from an existing installation into Wine drive and changing several registry keys... it was painful but I managed to do it (only the proofing worked) this way a while ago (I cannot reproduce it though)...

How to achieve that? I need only the proofing feature but the interchangeable interface language feature would be nice too. Does anyone have a suggestion in this topic?

I'm using the x86 version of course, because (according to WineHQ) the x64 version is not yet supported by Wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally completed the task doing the following:

1. Copy the data of the Office installer disc to a folder
2. Copy the data of the Language pack disc to the same folder (DO NOT OVERWRITE ANYTHING)
3. Modify the `config.xml` file inside the `ProPlus.WW` folder (the name might differ based on the Office version you have).

   - Add a line somewhere between the opening and closing `Configuration` tag like the following (change the language identifiers, check the folder names on the language installer disc if you're not sure about the correct string): `<AddLanguage Id="en-us" ShellTransform="yes"/> <AddLanguage Id="hu-hu" />`
4. Install using PlayOnLinux, by selecting Office 2010 using the `setup.exe` file in the folder you created in step 1. Select Microsoft Office 2010 when the installer asks you what to do.
5. Run `Setlang.exe` or open the Options dialogs Language part in one of the Office apps to change the language and proofing settings

Comment: (( and also: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22248 ))

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved much more conviently. IF you install Office through playonlinux you can afterwards just download a language pack e.g. from [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?ocmsassetID=fx010211366&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB#ID0EAADAAA=Office_2010). Than you open up playonlinux -> go to Miscellaneous tab -> Run .exe file in this virtual drive, and than choose your downloaded language. It installs automatically.

Comment: This didn't work for me back then... but I'm unsure what was the error... it was a POL error and that's it, couldn't run the exe file.